# Objective C message to all online clients

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS App where people can post something to their wall. Now I would like to make a function that, when a client posts something, everyone who is online (application active state) can see a message that tells them that someone just posted something.

I have been using Sinch.com, Quickblox.com etc.

- Sinch is bad, delay and slow, and it cannot send messages to over 10 clients. And it's for chatting, not for notification.
- Quickblox is good, but it has a really high price and it's for chatting too.

I have tried to use PushRemoteNotification, but this depends on whether users turn on notification permission or not. Even if they enable notification, it is really slow when I send a message to over 500 clients through Push, and also I don't know which devices are online, so I believe this is not a solution.

I am planning to use [PHP Ratchet WebSocket](http://socketo.me/) server and use one of these WebSocket libraries for my app [Objective-C SocketRocket client](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket) or [JetFire](https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire), but this is just my plan. So do you think it's possible for a huge amount of online clients?

If there is anyone who has any better idea please help.

Comment: For real time reaction, web socket it suggested. In other way, they are not so good compared to web socket, but they cost less.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you are looking for, but I've had a lot of success using [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which is built on top of Python. It has good functionality for building socket connections that allow pushing data from the server to clients. Ray Wenderlich's site has a [great tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) on Twisted (and specifically using Twisted with an iOS app) that helped me quite a lot.

Alternatively, [socket.io](http://socket.io), which is built on top of node.js would probably suit your needs quite well.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I hear about Twisted, I will study this and try.

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to check the tutorial. I think it will suit your needs quite well. Also, pay particular attention to the Twisted `lineReceived` functionality. Essentially it allows you to easily have the Twisted server respond with a callback to received lines of text, which would likely be perfect for your situation. You can have the Twisted server push the received lines out to the necessary clients.

Comment: Does it has broadcast message from one to others? Client message -> Twisted server -> broadcast this message to all other clients.

Comment: Yes, this functionality is very easy to implement with Twisted. I had a server up and running in a few hours that allowed a line of text to be received from an iOS app to the Twisted server, which is then easily pushed to all connected clients. If you go through and understand the tutorial, then you will be able to implement this pretty easily I think.